# Iterate over all Array indexes within array with map method Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

Been struggling with this for some time now and would appreciate any insight you guys have..

This is what my JSON Data looks like..[image]

BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs [Array] > BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects [Array]

I need to display each "Defect" on a grid table, which is inside the array of BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects which will look something like this [image]

What I have so far is `{this.state.rows.map((qc) => <div className="row table">{qc.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs[0].BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects[0].Defect}</div>`

This currently returns Hail Damage, Sunburn, Sunburn, Sunburn, **my question to you guys is how do I return all the defects from the whole array not just [0]**

Comment: Can you make an StackBlitz or Codepen example to check the code? On the other hand, if you want to `iterate` not only on 0 you can do `this.state.rows.map((qc, index) => allothercode). Cheers, sigfried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flattenDeep) for collection manipulation.

But you could also use nested [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
{
    this.state.rows.map((qc) =>
        qc.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs.map((qc2) =>
            qc2.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects.map((qc3) =>
                <div className="row table">
                    {qc3.Defect}
                </div>
            )
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply my man, but this is working perfectly...Cheers!